# depth function usage in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I tried to use the glDepthFunc in OpenGL ES 2.0 (at PC with emulator) and i don't understand the behavior.

In init function i only call define these values:

```
glClearDepthf( 0.5f );
glClearColor ( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
```

And in drawing function this code:

```
glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glUniform4fv(unifColor, 1, verColor);
glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4 );
eglSwapBuffers
```

I'm drawing a green square (half of the screen size).
When the z value of the drawn square is 0.5.

I expect that the depth test will be TRUE and i'll see the green square drawn, but i see only red screen (the color that is used in clear color).
When i define the clear depth value to be 1.0 i receive the expected behaviour: grren squar on red screen, so i think the depth is used as needed (all the initialzed defines for depth).

What can be the problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that could go wrong. There might be some precision issues. However, I have some guess here:

> I'm drawing a green square (half of the screen size). When the z value of the drawn square is 0.5.

Wrriting somehting like (x, y, 0.5, 1)  to `gl_Position` will **not** result in a window space z value of 0.5, but in 0.75.
The NDC coords of [-1,1] are mapped to the [depth range](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDepthRangef.xml) (by default [0,1]). Try drawing at z=0 to get a window space z value of 0.5 (and be prepared for additional precision issues).
All this assumes that there is no further transformation, especially no perspective, of course.